# Logstash: Output: Success or Failure Condition handling and Email trigge

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

Task:
Pulling data from SQLServer and Pushing records to Elasticsearch.
Achieving this through triggering the logstash cmd after certain upstream conditional triggers finished.

Planning to do this by cmd.exe in c#.net process. Any better way to achieve?

Scenario to handle:

Need to send email if data transfer completed successfully.

Need to send email if unsuccessful and also perform some event.
Unsuccessful Condition: Could be anything like server not available/disk full.

Also can we capture the last record transferred to Elasticsearch in the same consecutive request in case of failure and trigger some event?

First two are V important.

Also facing issue when ES stopped "dead ES instance" in logs/command window output, but LS dont stop waits for ES? How to get this out/terminate when no response after say 5 attempts by LS to ES?

Answer (score 0):

Logstash usually isn't a batch command to be triggered.

If your data is in SQLServer, try connecting with the [JDBC input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html).

Comment: thank you for reply. We have many ways to achieve this in .net one of them is nest bulk updating, but the reason to choose logstash is to achieve the maximum performance. I was able to achieve this with logstash by running it as process + other activities like sending email while success/failure with error log. But there are few measures to be taken while we run it as process, dont read the output of the process. let me know if any one need more info on this